# react.js posting string or json through exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest

When someone clicks on `Signup` the logic I'm using to create a account is this:

1. First create a `User` in my database.

   ```
   createUser = () =>{
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/user/');
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   xhr.send(JSON.stringify({  }));
   let that=this;
   xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
       if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
           that.state.newUser= this.responseText.toString();
       }
   };
   };
   ```
2. Then create the `LoginCredential` in my database :

   ```
   onButtonClick = () =>{

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/login/');
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   this.createUser();
   xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ email: this.state.email,passwordHash:this.state.passwordHash,user:JSON.parse(this.state.newUser) }));
   };
   ```

But this gives me error saying : `POST http://localhost:8080/login/` **400**

If I change the last line of the second step to : `xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ email: this.state.email,passwordHash:this.state.passwordHash,user:JSON.parse(this.state.newUser) }));`

Mainly the change is between `user:JSON.parse(this.state.newUser)` and `user:this.state.newUser`

In the second approach I get two exception :

1. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`
2. `Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.`

The exception `Spring Boot` providing :

`Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of 'com.mua.cse616.Model.User' (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (''); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of 'com.mua.cse616.Model.User' (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('')`

**What is wrong here ? How to fix it ?**

`this.state.newUser` holds value something like this `{"userID":577}`

I'm using Spring Boot in my server side. All of the `Controller` classes are annotated with `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")`

If needed for some reason, my `User` class :

```
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue Long userID;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = LoginCredential.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "userID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private LoginCredential loginCredential;
}
```

And `LoginCredential` class :

```
public class LoginCredential {
    @Id @GeneratedValue Long userID;
    String eMail;
    String passwordHash;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    User user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs because the application server and client both are running on the localhost on different ports. So, you need to specify your client application that your server is also running on same host but on a different port.

first, do in your react application

> npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
>
> add setupProxy.js file in public/src/

```js
//run defferent ports for website and api server 
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api/', { target: 'http://localhost:8080/' })); //make change as per your need
};
```

### if you are not using '/api/' then replace it with '/'.

Comment: front-end port : `3000`, back-end port : `8080`

Comment: they do, do you have a solution actually ?

Comment: I have worked without `http-proxy-middleware` before

Comment: I wish I had, I tried your code , I got : `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

Comment: make sure you are creating this file in frontend/public/src folder and you have installed npm in your front end.

Comment: first tell me you are using create-react-app or anything else?

Comment: it doesn't work, it's in `public/src/` and used *create-react-app*